# Laravel Valet nginx location regex not working on Mac Catalina

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location, laravel-valet

I'm working with Laravel Valet but when adding some regular expression location that works perfectly on forge Linux server, doesn't work for MacOS. It doesn't give any errors just doesn't load any of the right css. The regex is for css/js versioning. See code below:

```
location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    try_files $uri $1.$2;
}
```

added just before

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ "/Users/home/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php" last;
}
```

in valet.conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a **custom Valet Driver**, it's just php and you can use it to play with the incoming request and return the desired url or response. In this case I created a LocalValetDriver in the project root folder and skip the numeric portion of the filename in the **isStaticFile** function, just remember to return true on the *server* function so your custom driver will be used.

For more info on custom drivers, feel free to visit [Valet's documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/valet#custom-valet-drivers).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using php 7.3 it can be because of it.
Check this [link](https://hackernoon.com/deprecations-and-changes-for-php-7-3-avoid-errors-7a5c4dbeaa8b)

Comment: I believe it's more related to the rewrite on the next line, but can't find a way to make it work. Linux VMs are also using 7.3.x and working.

Comment: Just tested on my MacOS Mojave: Check this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/O3mz1g6.png all is working fine.

Comment: But why did you add this part of code in valet.conf? Add it in valet/Nginx/name_of_your_site.domain

Comment: Also added it there, didn't make a difference. Added in general conf file cause it wouldn't affect any other site. and yes, it recognizes it but doesn't ignore the timestamps in style.284627198.css to style.css as I would expect it

Comment: Trying to force the browser to reload css, and—wasn't my idea—just have to deal with it at least for now